# Mui, When the value is changed with Value +=, focus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use MUI (for react).

I changed the value of MUI's input with vanilla JavaScript, but it doesn't work properly. For example, it overlaps with a placeholder, and the focus is not maintained even when the mouse is removed.

Is there any way?

Since it is an in-house virtual keyboard implemented with vanilla JavaScript, the mui component cannot be modified.

Sorry for bad english.

The way to add characters on the virtual keyboard.

```
document.activeElement.value += 't'
```